# Please help me in splitting the middle term of this polynomial

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have been trying to solve this polynomial by splitting the middle term for quite sometime now but am unable to do it.Help on splitting this middle term would be highly appreciated 
[image]

Comment: WHat do you mean "splitting" it? Also, this is not a polynomial, precisely because of the square root term.

Comment: sorry,modified it to make it a polynomial

Comment: @user296602 : by splitting i mean factoring middle term

Comment: Do you means: $$y^2+\sqrt{5}(2-\frac{1}{2})y-5$$ ?

Comment: Yes Emilio .I meant that. Thanks a lot.